# Can I install this Toshiba HDD in a MacBook?

Tags: macbook, toshiba-hard-drive

The internal HDD in my white MacBook is broken. I have a spare Toshiba laptop HDD which I plan to install in the MacBook but when I compare the broken MacBook HDD (Hitachi brand) and the Toshiba HDD side by side I see that there is an extra set of pins on the Toshiba.

The corresponding place on the Hitachi HDD is empty so I am a bit scared that when I push the Toshiba HDD in the pins may be deformed. Do you suggest using the HDD?

The extra pins I refer to can be seen on the rightmost side in the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it fits without FORCING it then you'll probably be OK.  Just compare the SATA/Power sockets to the drive's SATA/Power connectors, and pay attention to what you're doing as you're doing it.

If you are really nervous about it, perhaps consider contacting a Toshiba (or other) notebook repair depot and get them to do it.